# What's the best open source physics engine to use with JOGL?

Tags: 3d, opengl, physics, java, physics-engine

I have a past with jbullet but the existing jogl compatible sources and demos seems uncompleted. I have managed to implement it to an extent but still looking for a better documented engine with more demo applications.

My answer to this question is currently **JBullet** but wondering if there are any better and easier solutions.

Any ideas & suggestions?

Comment: I can't vouch for the Java bindings/ports, but I can say that Bullet is a great library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's JBullet in my opinion, more noise about it means better documentation, more growth, etc. I'm using JBullet and I've had no issues.

Comment: A long time passed after this question of mine and in the mean time I have believed in JBullet and spent some time on it. Now I'm really fine with the results. Totally integrated my jogl based transformation routines with it.Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need 2D physics (Bullet is 3D) you can use [the Java port of Box2D](http://www.jbox2d.org/), which works very nicely, is well documented and is used throughout the world.

You can go for the stable 2.0 port, which is rather old now, or the in development 2.1 port, which I use and find to be working well.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this can help you http://www.dyn4j.org/.